Is it possible to join two SwiftData models into a single list?
I have three models SwiftData - a parent Event related to two others. I am trying to write a query that joins the two sub-models and filters to only show the results that match the selected event.
MODELS
@Model
class Event: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var dateStart: Date = Date()
    var dateEnd: Date = Date()
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var flights: [Item1]?
    var events: [Item2]?
}

@Model
class Item1: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var dateStart: Date = Date()
    var dateEnd: Date = Date()
    
    @Relationship(inverse: \Trip.flights) var trip: Trip?
}

@Model
class Item2: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var address: String = ""
    var notes: String = ""
    var dateStart: Date = Date()
    var dateEnd: Date = Date()
    
    @Relationship(inverse: \Trip.events) var trip: Trip?
}

All of this is easy enough with a single model. I have a let variable defining the event and then focus on one of the items in the ForEach.
let event: Event

ForEach(event.item1!)

But I can't join the two models into a single variable without a host of errors.
I've tried a basic && in the ForEach but that gives an error that the array can't be converted to expected argument type Bool.
ForEach(event.item1! && event.item2!)

I've also tried a couple of queries but that has it's own errors.
@Query(filter: #Predicate<Item1>{ ($0.trip == trip) }) var item1: [Item1]
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Item2>{ ($0.trip == trip) }) var item2: [Item2]
    let mergedEvents = item1 + item2
    

Each query line gets an error that "Instance member 'event' cannot be used on type 'EventDetails'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"
And the final variable has an error that "Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Item1]' and '[Item2]'"
The end result I'm going for is a single list with both Item1 and Item2 on it, sorted by a common field "startDate."
If I could write straight sql I'd write a straightforward JOIN with a WHERE clause to limit the results to the event but I have no idea how to handle it in Swift.
Any suggestions?

Note, do not use ! in your code ever.
Also no need for Identifiable, the @Model already provides that.
To join two different types arrays (item1 and item2) you can use zip.
Then you could use .map to convert into an array of tuples.

It seems that you could have a single Item class just by making  address and notes optional. Also, rather than initialising all of the properties as an empty strings, use an appropriate initialiser.

Off topic but an sql JOIN is quite different from what you are trying to do here, this is more like using UNION

You can't join two @Query or join the results of @Query directly but what you can do is to create a protocol containing the properties that you want to show in your list and then let the model types conform to the protocol
protocol EventItem {
    var id: UUID { get } 
    var name: String { get }
    var dateStart: Date { get }
    var dateEnd: Date { get }
}

extension Item1: EventItem {}
extension Item2: EventItem {}

Then you can combine the two properties flights and events into an array of type [any EventItem]
Here I did it as a computed property in an extension to Event
extension Event {
    var allItems: [any EventItem] {
        ((events ?? []) + (flights ?? [])).sorted { $0.dateStart < $1.dateStart }
    }
}

and then you can use this array in a view
List(event.allItems, id: \.id) { item in
    HStack {
        Text(item.name)
        Spacer()
        Text(item.dateStart.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))
        Text(item.dateEnd.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))
    }
}


Perfect. Thank you so much!
